# what's new location PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP in grails 3.x

Tags: grails

i am trying to upgrade my project from grails 2.1.1 to 3.1.1

in my project with grails 2.1.1, this code run well for me..

```
def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP
```

but when i tried to run with grails 3.1.1 . i get some error..and if i remove this line, my project run well with out error..

this error where i try to compile with "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP"

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.akiong.maintenance.TemplateEmailController': Initialization of
bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEmailService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)
#57db4507' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#57db4507': B
ean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newIn
stance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.akiong.maintenance.TemplateEmailController': Initialization of bean failed; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEmailService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#57db4507' while setting be
an property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#57db4507': Bean instantiation via facto
ry method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; ne
sted exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingleto  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preIns
tantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
ns(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.
7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedW  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:
118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
ebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at vpcsmsmasking.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
        at vpcsmsmasking.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEmailService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#57db4507' while setti
ng bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#57db4507': Bean instantiation via
factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beansCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEmailSe
rvice': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#57db4507' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error crea
ting bean with name '(inner bean)#57db4507': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instant
iate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of
 class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreatio
nException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE
.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.
1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.spring   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7
.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
framework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.spring   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
framework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1240) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1240)
        at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:160) ~[grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1190) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.
1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#57db4507': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested except
ion is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.co
re.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#57db4507': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested except
ion is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.co
re.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1
.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:  at org.springframework
.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1
.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.Abs        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBe
anFactory.java:504)
tractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grail
s.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Object]: Factory method 'newInstance' threw exception; nested exception is org.grail
s.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        ... 37 more
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.newInstance(AbstractGrailsClass.java:138) ~[grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [com.akiong.TemplateEmailService]!
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.newInstance(AbstractGrailsClass.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
        ... 38 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP for class: org.grails.plugins.domain.DomainC
lasNo such property: PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP for class: org.grails.plugins.domain.DomainClassGrailsPlugin
sGrailsPlugin
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:999) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:999)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1854) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1854)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1830) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1830)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3737) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3737)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
        at com.akiong.TemplateEmailService.<init>(TemplateEmailService.groovy) ~[main/:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at com.akiong.TemplateEmailService.<init>(TemplateEmailService.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075) ~[springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.newInstance(AbstractGrailsClass.java:128) ~[grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
        ... 44 common frames omitted
        at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.newInstance(AbstractGrailsClass.java:128)
        ... 44 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

anyone know where i can find `PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP` in grails 3.1.1?

======================================================================

this is my code from grails 2.1.1.. i am trying to change this code to grails 3.1.1

```
def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP
def cleanUpGorm() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
    propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
}
```

how to clear session in grails 3.x?

i know without optimisation you will face the outOfMemory problems.

Comment: "anyone know where i can find PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP in grails 3.1.1?" - You can't.  What is it that you want to do what that if you could find it?

Comment: as i  said. i am trying to upgrade my project from grails 2.1.1 to 3.1.1...see my update post

Comment: It isn't clear what it is that you want to accomplish.  The property doesn't exist any longer so it doesn't make sense to clear it.  Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i want to clear  the session...how to clear session in grails 3.x?

Comment: just remove it, it's enough to clear hibernate session in Grails 3